# pandas drop duplicates from a dataframe(grouped) with some specific condition

Tags: python, string, pandas, group-by, duplicates

Hi all I have a dataframe whose content will be like

```
name,mv_str
abc,Exorsist part1
abc,doc str 2D
abc,doc str 3D
abc,doc str QA
abc,doc flash
def,plastic
def,plastic income
def,doc str 2D   ###i added this row for better clarity
```

My expected o/p should have .... per group get unique record-rows in the sense--for each mailid mv_str should not be similar type i:e 1st 2 words from one 'mv_str' should not be there in 2nd/any row  for that particular User name.

Note: comparision should happen per user name level.

```
name,mv_str
abc,Exorist part1
abc,doc str 2D   ###3D and QA removes as 1st 2 words "doc str" matched
abc, doc flash   ###only 1st word is matching, 2nd word does not
def,plastic
def,plastic income  #It should be present as only one word is matching
def,doc str 2D   ###this row should be there as this is for another User
```

please anybody help me forming the logic, or code sample will be great Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need first [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) strings in column `mv_str` by `whitespace` and create new `DataFrame` `df1`:

```
df1 = df.mv_str.str.split(expand=True)
print (df1)
          0       1     2
0  Exorsist   part1  None
1       doc     str    2D
2       doc     str    3D
3       doc     str    QA
4       doc   flash  None
5   plastic    None  None
6   plastic  income  None
7       doc     str    2D
```

Add original `DataFrame` `df` by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
print (df)
  name          mv_str         0       1     2
0  abc  Exorsist part1  Exorsist   part1  None
1  abc      doc str 2D       doc     str    2D
2  abc      doc str 3D       doc     str    3D
3  abc      doc str QA       doc     str    QA
4  abc       doc flash       doc   flash  None
5  def         plastic   plastic    None  None
6  def  plastic income   plastic  income  None
7  def      doc str 2D       doc     str    2D
```

Then [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) by columns `name`, `0` and `1`, first value remains:

```
print (df.drop_duplicates(['name',0,1]))
  name          mv_str         0       1     2
0  abc  Exorsist part1  Exorsist   part1  None
1  abc      doc str 2D       doc     str    2D
4  abc       doc flash       doc   flash  None
5  def         plastic   plastic    None  None
6  def  plastic income   plastic  income  None
7  def      doc str 2D       doc     str    2D
```

Remove columns `0`, `1`, `2` by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
print (df.drop_duplicates(['name',0,1]).drop([0,1,2], axis=1))
  name          mv_str
0  abc  Exorsist part1
1  abc      doc str 2D
4  abc       doc flash
5  def         plastic
6  def  plastic income
7  def      doc str 2D
```

Or better remove columns by selecting only `name` and `mv_str` columns:

```
print (df.drop_duplicates(['name',0,1])[['name','mv_str']])
  name          mv_str
0  abc  Exorsist part1
1  abc      doc str 2D
4  abc       doc flash
5  def         plastic
6  def  plastic income
7  def      doc str 2D
```

Comment: @jezrael-can you please explain few words , what you did above..I am a beginner so finding it hard to analyze.

Comment: Yes, I was find another solution. Give me a sec, I explain it.

Comment: Please check my explanation, I am not still 100% sure if I understand you.

Comment: @jazrael: suppose i have another row for name def as def doc str 2D... then I am losing that row here...which is not correct

Comment: Yes, but then why `def,plastic income` row is nor removed? I dont understand condition.

Comment: Yes, it is not removed, because in another group `def` ?

Comment: per User name ...mv_str should be compared, if first two words of any mv_str matched then drop_duplcates... See my edited question Once, Please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128683/discussion-between-loneranger-and-jezrael).

Comment: yes, this Works and now by this method I can play around comparison (which positional words should match ) conditions...Thanks a Lot.

Comment: Glad can help you!